# Are "type" and "features" mandatory fields in a GeoJSON file?

Tags: geojson

I have to create a GeoJSON file and I am not sure if the structure has to follow some rules or if it is relatively flexible. For example, is something like that right?

```
{
    "building": [
        {
            "building_id": "id1",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        13.067752,
                        54.359456
                    ],
                    [
                        13.070011,
                        53.359588
                    ],
                    [
                        13.070066,
                        53.359619
                    ],
                    [
                        13.070061,
                        53.359863
                    ],
                    [
                        13.070016,
                        53.359888
                    ],
                    [
                        13.047752,
                        54.369456
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "household": [
                {
                    "household_id": "household1",
                    "persons": [
                        {
                            "person_id": "person1",
                            "age": 45
                        },
                        {
                            "person_id": "person2",
                            "age": 55
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can check that from the specification https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946. There are also on-line validators like geojsonlint.com.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As User30184 says the spec is [available](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946) and easy to read

> 3.2.  Feature Object
>
> A Feature object represents a spatially bounded thing.  Every
> Feature object is a GeoJSON object no matter where it occurs in a
> GeoJSON text.
>
> o  A Feature object has a "type" member with the value "Feature".
>
> o  A Feature object has a member with the name "geometry".  The
> value
> of the geometry member SHALL be either a Geometry object as
> defined above or, in the case that the Feature is unlocated, a
> JSON null value.
>
> o  A Feature object has a member with the name "properties".  The
> value of the properties member is an object (any JSON object or a
> JSON null value).
>
> o  If a Feature has a commonly used identifier, that identifier
> SHOULD be included as a member of the Feature object with the name
> "id", and the value of this member is either a JSON string or
> number.

So, no your JSON is not GeoJSON.